# Why my table formula doesn't work?

Tags: org-mode

windows 10, emacs 26.1

In `my.org` I have a table with formulas:

```
| _id | notificationDate | notificationDate_hr |   expiresDate | expiresDate_hr |
|-----+------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------|
| 178 |    1542054884000 |                     | 1544824800000 |                |
| 870 |    1536844904000 |                     | 1539378000000 |                |
| 633 |    1539190765000 |                     | 1541800800000 |                |
| 634 |    1539190765000 |                     | 1541800800000 |                |
| 184 |    1542045137000 |                     | 1544565600000 |                |
| 185 |    1542045137000 |                     | 1544565600000 |                |
| 110 |    1542348620000 |                     | 1544911200000 |                |
|   7 |    1543213783000 |                     | 1545775200000 |                |
| 871 |    1536844841000 |                     | 1539550800000 |                |
| 756 |    1538629706000 |                     | 1542232800000 |                |
| 303 |    1541448895000 |                     | 1544824800000 |                |
| 865 |    1536847817000 |                     | 1539550800000 |                |
| 748 |    1538629709000 |                     | 1542232800000 |                |

#+TBLFM: $3='(format-time-string "<%F %H:%M>" (seconds-to-time (/ $2 1000)) t);N
#+TBLFM: $5='(format-time-string "<%F %H:%M>" (seconds-to-time (/ $4 1000)) t);N
```

So I place the caret in the table formula line and type

<kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> (`org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c`)

But columns 3 not fill.
In minibuffer I get message:

```
Local setup has been refreshed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be no empty line between the table and the table formula.
Delete that line and `C-c C-c` works like expected on the table formulas.